# Does reinstallation for the web application expire all cookies?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, web

If the web application was uninstalled and installed again.
Are the cookies expired or however cancelled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing a bit of guessing on what you are asking.

No, cookies do not expire but because you are asking about ASP.NET I believe you are asking about authentication cookies (i.e. the user login). The cookies themselves do not expire but by default they can be invalidated. ASP.NET encrypts the authentication cookie with a key. The key is called [machine key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx). Depending on the web server settings this key can be generated again when the application pool is recycled (i.e. when you redeploy the application). This would mean that the cookies are effectively invalid because they cannot be decrypted. To prevent this behavior you can put a constant key in your web.config so cookies won't be invalidated. This is also desired if you deploy on more than one server and the user does requests to both.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply.
How to put a constant key ? i mean in which tag and attribute in the config file ?

Comment: Check the article I have linked in my answer for where to put the key in the web.config. For the value you can Google ASP.NET Machine Key generator. Here is one - http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/generatemachinekey/

Comment: Thanks alot. This is exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, Cookies stores on client with host information. If any change happens on web application it should not expire cookies.